# Optimizing nested for loops in Python for numpy arrays

Tags: python, numpy, optimization

I am trying to optimize a nested for loop in python. Here is the code (Note: inputting the data needs not to be optimized):

```
Y=numpy.zeros(44100)
for i in range(len(Y)):
    Y[i]=numpy.sin(i/len(Y))
                              ### /Data^^
Z=numpy.zeros(len(Y))
for i in range(len(Y))
    for j in range(len(Y))
        Z[i]+=Y[j]*numpy.sinc(i-j)
```

How to best optimize code written for numpy arrays when nested for loops are involved?

EDIT: For clarity.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? what is the purpose of your code?

Comment: @Adelin This is a type of interpolation that is used in audio to sample the in-between sample values and as such nudge/speed up audio. I want it to run much quicker so I can solve minimization problems. The data is made up only for the purpose of speeding up the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess this only makes sense to do if you multiply the argument to sinc with some factor `f`.. But then you can use `numpy.convolve`:

```
def orig(Y, f):
    Z=numpy.zeros(len(Y))
    for i in range(len(Y)):
        for j in range(len(Y)):
            Z[i]+=Y[j]*numpy.sinc((i-j)*f)
    return Z

def new(Y, f):
    sinc = np.sinc(np.arange(1-len(Y), len(Y)) * f)
    return np.convolve(Y, sinc, 'valid')

In [111]: Y=numpy.zeros(441)
     ...: for i in range(len(Y)):
     ...:     Y[i]=numpy.sin(i/len(Y))

In [112]: %time Z = orig(Y, 0.9)
Wall time: 2.81 s

In [113]: %timeit Z = new1(Y, 0.9)
The slowest run took 5.56 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
10000 loops, best of 3: 109 µs per loop
```

For the really good speed have a look at `scipy.signal.fftconvolve`